# Searching file for string surrounded by two other known string?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

Question title may be kinda vague, but heres what im attempting to do.

I have a html file locally on my server which is changing fairly regularly. It has multiple occurrences of:

```
<p>Jumble of random text</p>
<p>More text</p>
```

And so on...

I want to be able to sort through all the different jumble of random text's till it finds the one I am looking for, for example 'random', which could be anywhere in the file. Then I want a variable assigned to

```
Jumble of random text
```

Everything between the:

```
<p> and </p>
```

So far I have this:

```
echo grep -i 'random' search.html | grep -o -P '(?<=<p>).*(?=</p>)' search.html
```

Which works to an extent, however it is finding the first occurrence
and the last occurrence of the paragraph tags, therefore giving me a huge output of meaningless data, ie in this case:

```
Jumble of random text
More text
```

How can i get it to just return:

```
Jumble of random text
```

Getting very confused, very fast.

Comment: what about `grep -o -P '(?<=<p>).*(?=</p>)' search.html| grep -i random` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the match pattern `.*` is what is known as a **greedy match**, meaning that it will return the *largest* string to match your search pattern.

What you would want to do is to use a **non-greedy** (or *lazy*) match, which returns the *shortest* string to match your pattern. You can do this by changing your greedy match from `.*` to `.*?`. However, `grep` typically doesn't support this by default, but you can enable this by using the `-P` option which allows perl-like regex matching.

In short, you can change your grep command to `grep -o -P '(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)'`.

More details on this answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027518/non-greedy-grep

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that still doesn't work. Any ideas why?
EDIT: Ahh seems like it doesnt work in some versions. I shall see what version of grep i have.

Comment: @JamesHiey What is the exact command you're running - in your question you've shown the command as `echo cat ...` which is an unusual command combination to say the least ;-)

Comment: `echo grep -i 'random' search.html | grep -o -P '(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)' search.html`

Where search.html contains:
`<p>Jumble of random text</p>
<p>More text</p>
`

Comment: Most likely completely wrong...

Comment: @JamesHiey In short: yes. `echo` simply repeats things given to it, so in this case would send `grep`, `-i`, `random` and `search.html` through a pipe to another `grep`. What you would actually want is something more like `grep -o -P '(?<=<p>).*(?=</p>)' search.html`. This calls `grep` showing `-o`nly matching strings, using `-P`erl-like regex matching, on the file `search.html`.